# "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" in reading file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I found this type of question has been asked a lot of times, but I have not got a simple case like me :(

I have a test.txt file

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

I wrote the following Python code

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
file_0 = 'test.txt'
a0 = pd.read_csv(file_0, header = None)
#a0_df = pd.DataFrame(a0)
print(a0)
print(a0.iloc[:,1])
```

It lead to the following error message

```
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I want to get `2 5 8`, where things go wrong?

Comment: Maybe it has read entire `1 2 3` in one column, try specifying separator..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not need to `import csv` because you do not use that module.

Second, your file is not a *comma*-separated values. It is *space*-separated. You have to tell the reader about that:

```
a0 = pd.read_csv(file_0, sep="\s+", header = None)
```